# How to write on a specific line in a file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I want to write some data on an already existing file. It is a file that contains about 8-10 lines of header(# comments) and then thousands of lines of `data values`. What i want is to keep the header same but add the updated `data values` to the file. It is quite possible that after the update I have less number of lines of `data values`.

So basically i want to erase everything after the  last # comment in the header and then start writing the new values from there onwards. Is that possible?

Here is an example:

> ***Original File***

```
#Program
#Date
#Hello
0 23 23 54
1 12 4 2
2 253 786 9887
3 3 23 54
4 1 4 4
5 23 6 81
```

> ***Updated File***

```
#Program
#Date
#Hello
0 2 23 54
2 253 786 9887
5 23 6 81
```

The code i am editing is using `fopen` to read the file and `fprintf` to write to it. I would prefer if the answers are along these lines so that i don't have to change those two.

Comment: Why are you using `fopen`? In c++ you should use `std::fstream`.

Comment: The software I am working on uses fopen.

Comment: Ah well... Just would've been easier with `getline` ;)

Comment: I know. I tried that but the software is too big for me to change that. A lot of other stuff doesn't work if i use other than fopen.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I came up with is open the `Original File`, read and copy the header in to memory such as a `string header`. Then overwrite the whole file by writing the `header`, then the new data

Comment: Are you suggesting to write over the existing file? Because that's not really the best idea, at least if you're concerned about corrupt data when something goes wrong during writing.

Comment: @jrok I didn't *suggest* that, the OP does. As OP's first sentence in the question: "I want to write some data on an already existing file."

Comment: @jrok If i do not completely rewrite/overwrite, then what is the alternative?

Comment: @detraveller write a new file, delete the old one, rename the new one to the old name.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that reads the headers from the file and store them into a class/variable/struct.

Write a function that writes the headers to the file

Write a function that writes the desired values to the file

Execute all three functions in that order. The fact that it is the same file that you overwrite is irrelevant, just be sure to close it before writing back to it